# sys_getloadavg() returning false in PHP 7.2.4

Tags: php

I'm using PHP 7.2.4 on a siteground dedicated server and calling sys_getloadavg() but it's returning false.  I have searched but have not found an answer.

Comment: What OS is the code running on?  On Windows it will return (bool)FALSE.

Comment: it's running on centOS 6.9